# How to create a wamp 3.1.9 dev environment with a legacy Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, wampserver

I am trying to configure my dev environment based on Wamp 3.1.9 (most recent version until now) to receive a Zend Framework 2 project following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41-qEbpG2XQ.

The project don't have the composer.phar file, so I downloaded the Zend Framework Skeleton version 2.2.6 ( https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/releases ), I executed the command:

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

and

```
php composer.phar install
```

After that the Zend Framework Skeleton worked fine but, when I placed the project I need to work in, it just show the content of the file index.php on the screen as if I had printed the whole information instead of execute the PHP instructions/commands.

Opening the apache_error.log, it shows the following warning:

[Mon Oct 21 17:21:38 2019] [warn] Cannot get media type from 'x-httpd-php55'

I appreciate if some of you faced the same problem and could share the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching the internet about the error on the apache log file (apache_error.log). I found the solution.

The .htaccess file has the following instruction:

```
AddType x-httpd-php55 .php
```

I just commented this line using # and voilà, after refreshing the page I could see the first screen running properly.